# Express parsing multipart/form-data post in req.body

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, form-data

I'm trying to upload a file using jQuery Ajax + FormData object found on Chrome and Firefox browsers. The code I'm using to do it is the following:

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', $scope.image.data);

     $.ajax({
       url: '/wines/'+id+'/image',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false
     }).done(function(){
       $location.path('/');
     });
```

By looking at the developer tools I can see that the request is formed correctly, however express is recognising the contents inside req.body instead of req.files. Here is the request payload image:

[image: Request payload]

Express config:

```
app.configure(function(){
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app');
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(app.router);
});
```

What's what I am doing wrong??
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its not a file, its just a string. To AJAX a file with `FormData` you have to pass a File object to  `FormData.append` what you are passing is a data uri which is just a string.

A file in a `multipart/form-data` body looks something like this

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryNBylbsEYlWSsq2lB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="999.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

The file content here
------WebKitFormBoundaryNBylbsEYlWSsq2lB--
```

Comment: You're right, I was sending the FileReader result when I needed to send the raw file object